# String interpolation issue

Tags: sql, ruby

I am trying to save a record from the database to a variable "template_for_editing"

```
puts "select template id to edit"
template_id_to_edit = gets.chomp
template_for_editing = $db.execute %q{
SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = #{template_id_to_edit}
}
puts template_for_editing
```

I am getting the error code:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': unrecognized token: "#" (SQLite3::SQLException)
```

Comment: Rather than rely on creating your own SQL statements, and insert your variables into the strings, and then have to maintain/modify your SQL if you move to a different DBM, I'd highly recommend moving to using an ORM such as Sequel or Active Record. They'll save you all sorts of headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation doesn't work with `%q`, it works with `"`:

```
template_for_editing = $db.execute "SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = #{template_id_to_edit}"
```

BTW passing unmodified user input to SQL query like this is a prescription for disaster. I'm a user and I type:

```
1; DROP TABLE templates
```

And I drop your `templates` table.

Comment: Here's an explanation of the different notations with the percent sign: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation

Comment: Excellent, big thanks. Thanks for the heads up on the security issue also, but this code is for a personal project that only I will be using so I'm not too fussed.